# Jquery toggle div, allow clicking outside of div to close, also allow everything inside the div clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a toggle event on a div, and I've seen many questions regarding mine but nothing seems to work for what I'm trying to do, it either makes my div disappear in a few seconds, or it just doesn't work. Here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmLdp45s/2/).

I have a div that needs to toggle when another `<div>` is clicked. The toggled div has inputs in it that need to be filled out, and a submit button inside it as well. So I need clicks inside the div to be allowed, but only inside my div. So I want the div to show unless the user clicks outside of this div.

I'm using this query which toggles fine:

```
$('#MyDiv').click(function (event) {
  $("#ToggledDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

And then this coding to hide it when clicked outside of the div which doesn't work:

```
$(window).click(function () {
  $("ToggledDiv").hide();
});
```

I've tried solutions with e.preventDefault(); but that doesn't work, or $(document).click, even mousedown but it just doesn't flow how I want, it'll hide it within a few seconds, or it will prevent the toggle from even working so I'm lost.

Comment: you can use jquery `not` like so `$(window).not('#ToggleDiv').click(function () {
  $("#ToggledDiv").hide();
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this behavior is [Event Bubbling and Capturing](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) of HTML DOM API.
 You can use [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) OR `event.cancelBubble = true` to prevents the event from bubbling up to the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event. 
Another good article: [events order](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

```js
$('#MyDiv').click(function(event) {
  $("#ToggledDiv").show();

  disabledEventPropagation(event);
  //console.log('2nd event');

});

$('#ToggledDiv').click(function(event) {

  disabledEventPropagation(event);
  //console.log('3rd event');

});


$(document).click(function() {
  $("#ToggledDiv").hide();
  //console.log('1st event');

});


function disabledEventPropagation(event) {
  if (event.stopPropagation) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  } else if (window.event) {
    window.event.cancelBubble = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="MyDiv" style="background-color:yellow">
  click me to open
</div>


<div id="ToggledDiv" style="display: none;background-color:yellow">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `event` when you click inside the `#targetDiv`.  There are two properties you can use to evaluate what action to perform: `event.target` and `event.currentTarget`.  In this case:

```
$('#ToggledDiv').on('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target, event.currentTarget);
});
```

This is a good way to see if what clicked is actual target or a child element in the target.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Chris' answer, you can see here that I check that the `e.target` is not inside the form using vanilla [Node.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains), and also not the button...

https://jsfiddle.net/jmLdp45s/3/

```
var $button = $('button');
var $form = $('form');

$button.click(function() {
  $form.slideToggle();
});

$(window).click(function(event) {
  if (
    !$form.get(0).contains( event.target ) // target is not inside form
    && event.target !== $button.get(0) // target is not button
  ) $form.hide();
});
```